# Highcharts add a Mean line to BoxPlot chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Is there a way to add another line to the bar in the BoxPlot chart which will represent the Mean (Average)?**  This will look like the Median line which is automatically drawn for you in the below Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tLucL6mq/3/
Fiddle code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'boxplot',
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Sample Base Salary Range'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['4', '3', '2', '1', '0'],
        title: {
            text: 'Job Level'
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Base Salary'
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        boxplot: {
            fillColor: '#F0F0E0',
            lineWidth: 2,
            medianColor: '#0C5DA5',
            medianWidth: 3
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: "Observation Data",
        data: [
            ['0', 68, 75, 79, 82, 84, 89],  //level 4 - category 0
            ['1', 53, 63, 68, 72, 75, 79],  //level 3 - category 1
            ['2', 47, 52, 59, 64, 67, 68],  //level 2 - category 2
            ['3', 35, 37, 39, 42, 46, 51],  //level 1 - category 3
            ['4', 32, 33, 34, 38, 40, 45]   //level 0 - category 4
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.series.name}</b><br/><em>Job Level: {point.x}</em><br/>',
            pointFormat:  '- Max: {point.high}<br/>' +
                          '- Q3: {point.q3}<br/>' +
                          '- Median: {point.median}<br/>' +
                          '- Q1: {point.q1}<br/>' +
                          '- Min: {point.low}<br/>'
        }
    }, {
        name: "Outlier Data",
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [ // x, y positions where 0 is the first category
            [0, 74],
            [1, 67],
            [4, 40],
            [4, 48]
        ],
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'yellow',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#0C5DA5'
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.series.name}</b><br/><em>Job Level: {point.x}</em><br/>',
            pointFormat: 'Base Salary: {point.y}'
        }
    }]

});
```

I'm not seeing in the docs how to do this...  Is this possible at all?

Also, in the example, when you hover any part of the boxplot, the tooltip pops up.  **Is there a way to show the tooltip when you hover the Median or one of the Quartiles so that it only shows that data point's info?**
I'm thinking it would be similar to how the tooltip for the scatter series shows data for individual points.

---

**Edit:**
I finally got my head around the syntax to pass in point objects instead of the array of values for each data set.  After getting that object syntax correct, I added a new property for `mean` and included that value in the tooltip.

http://jsfiddle.net/tLucL6mq/4/

```
series: [{
        name: "Observation Data",
        data: [
{x: '0', low: 68, q1: 75, median: 79, q3: 82, high: 84, mean: 77.6},  //level 4 - category 0
{x: '1', low: 53, q1: 63, median: 68, q3: 72, high: 75, mean: 66.2},  //level 3 - category 1
{x: '2', low: 47, q1: 52, median: 59, q3: 64, high: 67, mean: 57.8},  //level 2 - category 2
{x: '3', low: 35, q1: 37, median: 39, q3: 42, high: 46, mean: 39.8},  //level 1 - category 3
{x: '4', low: 32, q1: 33, median: 34, q3: 38, high: 40, mean: 35.4}   //level 0 - category 4
        ],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.series.name}</b><br/><em>Job Level: {point.x}</em><br/>',
            pointFormat:  '- Min: {point.low}<br/>' +
                          '- Q1: {point.q1}<br/>' +
                          '- Median: {point.median}<br/>' +
                          '- Q3: {point.q3}<br/>' +
                          '- Max: {point.high}<br/>' +
                          '- Mean: {point.mean}<br/>'
        }
    }
```

This is almost what I wanted, but ideally, I would like to see the `mean` line displayed on the box for each data set just like the `median` line is.

Comment: How will you calculate the mean of your data?

Comment: It would be ideal if it could be set on the point object the same way that the low, high, q1, q3, and median are set in the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/box-plot-series).  But as it doesn't appear that this is a built in option, I'm looking for another way to add it in.

Comment: No what i asked is, you have 4 data sets so how will you calculate the mean and is the mean for whole graph?

Comment: No, the mean is not for the whole graph.  I'm looking to place a mean line on each bar in the graph - just like the median line (probably a different color, or otherwise styled differently).  I've seen the "theoretical mean" that is drawn as a graph plot line for the whole graph on some of their examples.  What I'm after is a line drawn on each of the boxes just like the median line. And just like the median value is passed in, I would expect to pass in the mean value.  I will update my post with an updated fiddle.

Comment: It's not what you're asking for, but, when I do this I have always plotted the mean using a scatter series with a different styling from the outlier scatter series (in my case, usually a red square or diamond), like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/dkvsax9d/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it's not supported to add such line, but it's Highcharts, so you can extend default functions: http://jsfiddle.net/tLucL6mq/5/ ;)

Simple snippet:

```
(function (H) {

    // when changing point format for boxplot, values will calculate automatically
    H.seriesTypes.boxplot.prototype.pointArrayMap = ['low', 'q1', 'median', 'q3', 'high', 'mean'];

    H.seriesTypes.boxplot.prototype.toYData = function (point) {
        return [point.low, point.q1, point.median, point.q3, point.high, point.mean];
    };

    // draw lines after default drawPoints is called:
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.boxplot.prototype, 'drawPoints', function (p) {
        p.call(this);
        var chart = this.chart,
            r = chart.renderer,
            xAxis = this.xAxis,
            yAxis = this.yAxis,
            x, y;

        // for each point, draw line: 
        H.each(this.points, function (p, i) {
            x = p.shapeArgs.x;
            y = p.meanPlot;

            if (p.meanPlotX) {
                // update existing path:
                p.meanPlotX.attr({
                    d: ['M', x, y, 'L', x + p.shapeArgs.width, y]
                });
            } else {
                // create mean-line for the first time
                p.meanPlotX = r.path(['M', x, y, 'L', x + p.shapeArgs.width, y]).attr({
                    stroke: 'black',
                        'stroke-width': 2
                }).add(p.series.group);
            }

        });
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

**Extra:**

It will work with your previous format `[x, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6]` because of the first two methods (`pointArrayMap` and `toYData`), of course in case y6=mean: http://jsfiddle.net/tLucL6mq/7/

Comment: Do you know of a way to get a tooltip for each `y` value in the data set?  Meaning if I hover the median/mean/q1/etc, can I get a tooltip for just that `y` value (as if it was a point in a scatter series)?

Comment: I think you can't - it's one point and tooltip is displayed per point, not per part of the point.

Comment: How would you implement this in Angular Highcharts?

Comment: The same way @Alex - copy my snippet and paste where you initialize Highcharts.